# code compression for multiple search/highlight

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I've been looking for a way to search for a list of numbers within a lengthy excel sheet, I need to find rows and highlight them black with white text. There are about 30 numbers that I am looking for.

So far:

Sub Reformat()

```
Dim SrchRng1 As Range
Dim c1 As Range, a As String

Set SrchRng1 = ActiveSheet.Range("G1", ActiveSheet.Range("G65536").End(xlUp))
Set c1 = SrchRng1.Find("217", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c1 Is Nothing Then
    a = c1.Address
    Do
        With c1.EntireRow
            .Font.ColorIndex = 2
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 1
        End With
        Set c1 = SrchRng1.FindNext(c1)
    Loop While c1.Address <> a
End If

Dim SrchRng2 As Range
Dim c2 As Range, b As String

Set SrchRng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("G1", ActiveSheet.Range("G65536").End(xlUp))
Set c2 = SrchRng3.Find("317", LookIn:=xlValues)
If Not c2 Is Nothing Then
    f = c2.Address
    Do
        With c2.EntireRow
            .Font.ColorIndex = 2
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 1
        End With
        Set c2 = SrchRng2.FindNext(c2)
    Loop While c2.Address <> b
End If
```

Does what I need it to do, is there a way to compress this down and/or make it so I can stop setting SrchRng1,2,3 etc... or declaring a,b,c etc... as String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (see inline comments for explanations)

```
Sub Reformat()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SrchRng As Range
    Dim SearchValues() As Variant
    Dim cl As Range, addr As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' load values to find into array, by whatever means you choose
    SearchValues = Array(217, 317)

    ' Define range to search. Only need to do this once
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set SrchRng = Range(.Cells(1, 7), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp))
    End With

    ' Loop thru your search values
    For i = LBound(SearchValues) To UBound(SearchValues)

        Set cl = SrchRng.Find(SearchValues(i), LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not cl Is Nothing Then
            addr = cl.Address
            Do
                With cl.EntireRow
                    .Font.ColorIndex = 2
                    .Interior.ColorIndex = 1
                    .ClearContents
                End With
                Set cl = SrchRng.FindNext(cl)
            Loop While Not cl Is nothing ' cl.Address <> addr
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

To format rows *Not* in the search list is best done with a `AutoFilter`

```
Sub ReformatByExclusion()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim SrchRng As Range
    Dim SearchValues() As Variant
    Dim cl As Range, addr As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' load values to find into array, by whatever means you choose
    '  Note, Autofilter requires values as strings, 
    '  even when the data in the sheet are numbers
    SearchValues = Array("217", "317")

    ' Define range to search. Only need to do this once
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        Set SrchRng = Range(.Cells(1, 7), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp))
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Filter for values in your search list
    SrchRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=SearchValues, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ' Format rows excluded by filter
    For Each cl In SrchRng.Cells
        With cl.EntireRow
            If .EntireRow.Hidden Then
                .Font.ColorIndex = 2
                .Interior.ColorIndex = 1
                .ClearContents
            End If
        End With
    Next
    SrchRng.AutoFilter
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to flip this around so that anything that is Not in the search gets the action?

Comment: excellent, now is there a way to clear the contents of the row that gets highlighted? when I add .ClearContents under the Interior.ColorIndex = 1 it seems to break and change all lines...

Comment: @Kalzin I've added `ClearContents` in, it works fine in my test case.

Comment: ok, I must have not gotten all of it. one last thing, the search looks for the numbers in any form ie: 3178887615 and 3453174645 are both removed... is there a way to force it to only read the first 3 digits?

Comment: @Kalzin which version of the code?  the `Find` _might_ do this, depending on the settings last used.  You should explicitly set _all_ paramters for the `Find` to avoid this risk.  You should reset the `FindFormat` too.

Comment: @Kalzin Also, if you want to match numbers that _Begin_ with your specified values, it might be easier to use the AutoFilter for either inclusive or exclusive searches.  Just use `If Not .EntireRow.Hidden Then` to change the sence

Comment: Trying to use the most recent version with autofilter and clearcontents. if only I had enough rep to move this to a conversation. :(